# How to convert .ui to py in windows ?

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyuic

I followed this [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLxIO-2obQAhUBqY8KHYshBaEQFgghMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F22266802%2Fhow-to-convert-a-ui-file-to-py-file&usg=AFQjCNEo35w7kU_wF2-L65swxf7cEPjHTw&sig2=DkoM1lbQZu3ETnMv0hNNiQ) to convert .ui to .py using python in windows but its not working.I tried installing pyuic4 but its not working. Is there any tools or libraries in python for doing it? Please suggest .

Comment: Are you using PyQt4 or PyQt5? And please be specific on "its not working".

Comment: the pyuic4 not on the path environment? be specified about it?

Answer (score 4):

why not just import it?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = uic.loadUi('demo.ui')
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

ps: sorry i cant answer in comment section. my reputation too low

Answer (score 0):

have an application created to convert the .ui (Pyqt5 Created by qt designer) file to py ( you can use for windows it will work perfectly)

you can convert your file easily using this application,
Direct Download Link: https://download1653.mediafire.com/utmxc4pza7ug/1f0gkwk6577g7fi/Ui+to+Py.zip

Mediafire link to download: https://www.mediafire.com/file/1f0gkwk6577g7fi/Ui_to_Py.zip/file

you check the source code of the application on my GitHub: https://github.com/Harvindar994/

tags: python, pyqt5, qt designer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).