# Converting .ui to .py with Python 3.6 on PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.6

I can't convert ui to py

it's giving this:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert .ui to py in windows ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354127/how-to-convert-ui-to-py-in-windows)

Answer (score 35):

Instead of installing Python packages by hand, I would consider using `conda` and `pip` from a recent `Anaconda` install (https://www.anaconda.com/download/).

After installing Anaconda with `python 3.6`, open a privileged (`Run as Administrator`) `cmd` or git `bash` and run the following commands:

**Installing PyQt5**

PyQt5 is the default one for Python 3.6. You can check available packages by running (`conda search pyqt`)

```
conda install pyqt
```

**Generating .py file from .ui**

```
python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x [FILENAME].ui -o [FILENAME].py
```

**Importing generated .py on your Python code**

Now, suppose that your file is called `MainWindow.py`, and its type is `QMainWindow`. This is how you import it on Python

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
import sys

class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = ApplicationWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 20):

you are using the correct syntax: `pyuic5 -x file.ui -o file.py`

but you have to make sure that the `file.ui` is in the same location of your `pyuic5.bat`

Comment: Yes. It's in the same location.

Answer (score 13):

```
python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x [FILENAME].ui -o [FILENAME].py
```

This worked for me. Thanks to Danilo Gasques

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for my bad english

1. You can find file "pyuic5.exe" (For example it is "C:\Python\venv\Scripts\pyuic.exe")
2. Through the command line go to the folder with the file "needToConvert.ui"
3. Enter the following command line: C:\Python\venv\Scripts\pyuic.exe needToConvert.ui -o needToConvert.py

Answer (score 1):

What you need is python3.dll file which is missing and you have to place in your python directory

- Go here (https://winpython.github.io/).
- Download the version of python you have and also see which bit
  version
- Download the zero version and extract it somewhere temporarily
- In extracted folder search for python3.dll in the search bar
- Extract where your python setup is and try then it will work

Answer (score 0):

Use this .bat file to automatically convert all *.ui files to python files.
All you need is:

1. Save the script below to ui2py.bat file
2. Edit the file with notepad and specify the **pythonPath** directory from your PC
3. Save changes and execute the ui2py.bat file convertor

   @echo off

   rem set the python path
   set pythonPath=G:\Programming\WinPython-64bit-3.6.3.0Qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64

   echo [START] converting .ui files...

   rem convert all .ui files in current directory
   for %%i in (*.ui) do (

   rem Display the file name
      echo %%i   --  ui_%%~ni.py

   rem converting
      %pythonPath%\python.exe -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x %%i -o ui_%%~ni.py

   )

   echo [END] converting .ui files...